# Why does the del operator have a line under it, but the laplacian doesn't?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, index-notation

I'm studying through index notation and was wondering why the del operator has a line under it meaning its a vector, while the laplacian doesn't?

I'm quite confused because I thought that both of these can apply to scalar and vector fields

Comment: Del increases the order of the tensor field by one (scalar field lifted to vector field usually). Laplacian keeps the order the same (scalar field turns to scalar field, vector field turns to vector field). That said I don't really know what "line" notation you mean here.

Comment: Also notations may vary from author to author, so it might be better to include your source